# How to keep binder image from breaking for no reason and with no changes

Tags: mybinder

My binder repo stopped launching and appears to give some error when installing packages from `apt.txt`. Nothing fundamentally has changed with the repo and the repo works fine when I run it locally with repo2docker.

Remote (fails to launch): https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/nasiegel88/airquality/HEAD

Local (works fine): `jupyter-repo2docker https://github.com/nasiegel88/airquality`

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/my-binder-repo-randomly-stopped-working/14525?u=fomightez). Please @Noah_Seagull, if you are going to crosspost, **note in all places where you crosspost**. Otherwise you can possibly take up time of multiple persons offering the same guidance. Additionally, it helps people in a similar situation find the best solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure that I would be an issue. I will make sure to note in the future if I ask the same question on different forums.

Comment: Not a big deal at all.  Good to get eyes.  Done it myself. There is a way to do it though to help all involved and that's why I pointed out the reasons behind the guidance.

Comment: I'll add this here for others coming a long later since I just added the same as comment to a similar recent question: This type of question would best be posted in the 'Binder' help category over at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org) as it involves more discussion usually to optimize what you can do. Stackoverflow discourages such discussions. Also, the 'pulse' of MyBinder can better be assessed there.